# Is it possible to make stroke only shapes in Photoshop without Stroke Path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, photoshop-effects

I often find myself stroked shapes for buttons etc (kind of like the "Ask Question" button on this site actually). I follow the approach of creating a white shape with a stroke effect, and then selecting the multiply blend mode. Leaving only the stroke visible. This is a useful technique as i can resize the shape.

So this is fine for the design stage but when it comes to exporting these elements as png's and using them in a website or in after effects, the multiply effect obviously won't be carried over and i'm having to reconstruct these elements in Illustrator. I do this often enough that it's getting a bit annoying.

Is there a different method that will allow me to create these type of elements fully within Photoshop that i can export as fully functional pngs? Without using Stroke Shape, as i can't resize these layers.

Here are some screenshots of the process:

- Make white shape
  [image: Make white shape]
- Add stroke
  [image: Add stroke]
- Multiply shape layer
  [image: Multiply shape layer]
- Desired final effect 
  [image: Final product]
- Multiply problems
  [image: No alpha]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I'd recommend going to the `Rounced rectangle` options and setting:

- `Fill` to none
- `Stroke` and `Stroke width` to what ever color / width you want.

<sub>You'll need to have one of the shape tools selected to see these options.</sub>

---

**Alternatively...** These can also be found in the `Window > Properties`

[image]

---

---

Shape Stroke was introduced in Photoshop CS6.

Comment: Wow, i've been overlooking that option for quite some time i guess! Thanks @Joonas

Answer (score 4):

Don't change the layer's blending mode. After you apply the stroke go to your Layer Panel and where it says **Fill: 100%** lower that to 0. It's directly below **Opacity**

Comment: I've always wondered what that option did! So obvious now. Can't believe i never looked into this. Thanks Ryan.

Comment: THIS is the right answer! Works for any type of shape (inkl. vector and mask based). Great, thanks!